# Inexpensive CDN with Origin/Pull services?

Tags: cdn, web

Does anyone know of an inexpensive CDN which offers origin/pull services?

I've looked into Cachefly, they look great but don't provide this service for less than $1k unfornuately.

If you know of an inexpensive CDN which provides these services and are reliable, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) now has custom-origin ability so it's no longer tied directly to an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket, although logging storage must be a S3 bucket. The only obstacle at the moment is you cannot create the custom-origin distribution via the AWS console yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check out softlayer.com

Comment: I've not used their CDN myself, but have adminned boxes from there. The CDN they have looks pretty good, and from very little money.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using http://www.coralcdn.org and you can't get cheaper...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Edgecast](http://www.edgecast.com/) before, and it was considerably less than $1k.

They do origin pull, and lots of other stuff.

No, i don't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/55396/cdn-recommendation

[Recommend a content delivery network (CDN) for a specific purpose](https://serverfault.com/questions/51323/recommend-a-content-delivery-network-cdn-for-a-specific-purpose)

Answer (score 0):

[Voxel](http://www.voxel.net/products-services/universal-transfer) is charging $0.10/GB

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give **VPS.net CDN** a try:

https://www.vps.net/cdn-signup

According to their [wiki](http://www.vps.net/wiki/cdn-origin-pull-setup) they support "Origin Pull".

- I don't work for them
- I haven't used their service

but their pricing looks very competitive.